# which OS requires minimum disk space to install?

Tags: installation, operating-systems, disk-space

which OS requires minimum disk space (it should have a basic desktop) ? 
The latest ubuntu requires 5gb https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/powerpc/memory-disk-requirements.html

while winXP requires 1.5GB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314865

Any other OS which requires even less?

Comment: A lot depends on what you define as *a basic desktop*. Base OS? Base OS plus graphical shell? GUI plus modern browser, mail client, office apps, vlc, ... ?

Comment: Gentoo, you can build up your system; if you want even less, try Linux From Scratch.

Comment: The right URL for Ubuntu information is: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/powerpc/minimum-hardware-reqts.html

Comment: @Hennes I need a base OS with Graphical shell...browser, mail client, office apps come later and not to be included in the minimum space requirement.

Comment: Damn Small Linux

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your needs. Do you need a GUI? Is this computer just for random messing around? You're hard pressed to find an OS that is less than 1.5 GB these days. Win 2000 is 650 MB, but  you'll run into compatibility issues with modern software.

Comment: Mike, I wont be using it as my primary machine, it will just be for messing around and I wont be installing too many modern softwares. Just a basic PC with a desktop